# Reading From field of an outlook message

Tags: email, c#-4.0, outlook

my question is that if i compose a mail in outlook, which is not configured for a user and following are the fields of mail message From,To,Subject and body. I saved this message in drafts of inbox. How can i read the from field of the message. All other fields can easily be read through Mail-item class. i couldn't find any help regarding this problem.
regards
Naveed

Comment: add more description to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The sender related properties are not set until the message is actually sent.